# Expo SplashScreen

Tags: react-native, expo, splash-screen

I have a question. for expo there is a initial white expo splashscreen at the start. I wonder will that splashscreen go away after we publish it on an app store. I have an animated splash screen in one of my project but when i test on expo it always show the expo splash screen first before showing in. How can I make my animated splash screen (a json file) the real splash screen? For now it is just an animation that run after the application is ready to use

I edit the background-color from App.json to fit well with my SplashScreen. But still I wonder if the expo splashscreen will appear in the publish version of the app

Answer (score 0):

Here is an an example provided by the expo to create animated splash screen

https://github.com/expo/examples/blob/master/with-splash-screen/README.md

or you can use this package for animated splash screen

https://github.com/fabio-alss-freitas/react-native-animated-splash-screen

or you can use

https://github.com/zoontek/react-native-bootsplash

here is an example to show animation on splash using json

https://github.com/zoontek/react-native-bootsplash-lottie-example

Comment: @Katy where you able to solve that issue ?